# Vaadin radio buttons, horizontal rather than stacked vertical

Tags: html, radio-button, vaadin, radiobuttonlist

I want to display my radio buttons in 1 line such as:

> ◎ Option1     ◉ Option2

However with Vaadin I cannot accomplish this it seems like the following,

> ◎ Option1
>
> ◉ Option2

here is my code:

```
final List<String> options = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
                "hebele", "hubele"});
        
        final OptionGroup group = new OptionGroup("", options);
        
        group.setNullSelectionAllowed(false); // user can not 'unselect'
        group.select("hubele"); // select this by default
```

How can i change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [The Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book), you've got to [define a theme](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html) to setup your own `style.css` file.

Then you can override the default style for the option to be displayed inline as follow:

```
.v-app .v-select-optiongroup .v-select-option {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: the class name was different but that solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: **UPDATE** In 2014, the default project automatically created by the [Vaadin plugin for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/) and [Vaadin plugin for Eclipse](http://vaadin.com/eclipse) both create a CSS file in a custom theme on your behalf. So all you need to do is find that file and modify it. In NetBeans, `Web Pages` > `VAADIN` > `themes` > `my theme` > `mytheme.scss`. That .scss file uses a superset of CSS that will be compiled automatically into the final CSS during a `Run` > `Clean and Build Project` operation.

Answer (score 8):

With Vaadin 7.3, Valo theme supports horizontal `OptionGroup` without writing custom style:

```
OptionGroup group = new OptionGroup("", options);
group.addStyleName(ValoTheme.OPTIONGROUP_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem like following.

```
RadioButtonGroup<String> radioGroupGtip = new RadioButtonGroup<>();
radioGroupGtip.getStyle().set("white-space","nowrap");
```